# How do I make my code play more than one song randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-requests, audio-player

I'm a bit new to this and I would need a little help with this;
I have this code that what it basically does is play you a song from the current directory you are in, I would like to know if you could somehow make it play more than one song randomly without repeating itself until the list is over. Thank you

```
    import random,os,sys

folder=os.listdir(os.getcwd())

file=random.choice(folder)
ext3=['.mp3']
print('First random pick: '+file)

while file[-4:] not in ext3 :
       
       print('Not an MP3 file  : '+file)
       file=random.choice(folder)
else:
       os.startfile(file)
       print('Song name: '+file)



##os.startfile(random.choice(folder))
```

Comment: do you want to make a shuffle playlist essentially?

Comment: use `random.shuffle` to set the queue, then play each song in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random, os, sys

folder = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

mp3s = [file for file in folder if file.endswith('.mp3')]
queue = random.shuffle(mp3s)
for file in queue:
    print('Song name:', file)
    os.startfile(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first run the program, create an array of current songs in the directory. Then, randomly play a song from the array. Once you begin playing a song, pop the song from the array so that the list only contains unplayed songs. Iterate over the array using the former logic to work through the array until no songs remain.

Comment: So many thanks but i have other problem;In this part of the code the if opens another script that is a music player, I would like to know how to make the main script keep running since I have to keep giving it orders and while the song is playing I can't.
if "música" in a: exec(open("C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\Desktop\\programaNate\\musica\\musica.py").read())